# How to use Densepose after successfully installing detectron2

Tags: image, opencv, detectron

I want to use densepose. For that I have successfully installed detectron2 in my windows and it is generating simple images fine. But I want to generate the image just like the one attached below and I am unable to generate it using densepose. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81o1D.jpg)

I wanted to generate the above attached image using densepose. But I am unable to download the required models for it and generate the script for it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.